# Wordpress - Multiple blog pages with same database table

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, blogs

I'm working on upgrading a website completely.
The current website has a blog set up which uses Wordpress.

Basically, I wanted to set up the new blog on the same server (the new site is in a seperate directory), but I want both of the blogs, the currently used one and the new one, to pull the same post information from the table.

Can anyone give me any help as to accomplishing this?

I don't want to accidentally end up clearing the table

Thanks, Tom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the same posts in both the sites, just point them to the same database in the configuration file (do not use the automatic install script - do all configuration manually in the config file). Note that they also will have most of the configuration shared as well, especially plugin configurations and the like.

And of course, back up your data before doing anything so you can revert back if you do something wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the manual configuration was what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can set a database sql prefix when installing Wordpress (default is wp_ I think)

Make sure you pick some other prefix :)

This will allow you to run multiple blogs on the same serve and in the same SQL database

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do that. Duplicate the wp-config.php files, including the secret keys. But why? What are you trying to do?

And realize that you have to keep exactly the same plugins in each WP install, because if you add a plugin to one that writes configs to the database, the other install will also look for that plugin and throw errors (at very least) when it doesn't find it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, but I wanted both of the blogs to use the EXACT SAME table, which im guessing wouldn't work if I changed the table prefix? Basically I want to have two blogs with the same post information on the same server, but just in seperately accessible directorys

Comment: has a point - there are better ways of doing this. You could, for example, use .htaccess to handle URLs in different 'directories' through the same index.php file.